# jquery. how to equal .text() .val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

I need to equal two value, but it's not work..

```
var rowID = $("#@idSelectObjectGuid").val();

$($(".ls-grid-body tr").children(".@vcTable.PrimaryKey")).each(function () {

   alert($(this).text() + " == " + rowID);

   if ($(this).text() == rowID) {

       $(".ls-grid-body tr").removeClass("lst-state-selected");
       $(this).addClass("lst-state-selected");

   }
});
```

alert result:

```
df5ebd84-14a1-4e57-9f38-32d4e84e1503 - 41 == df5ebd84-14a1-4e57-9f38-32d4e84e1503 - 36
```

Why first lenght is 41 and why they not equal...

How to do it?

Comment: is 41 your length?? From your code it seems to be rowid

Comment: @TusharGupta to be part of: `$(this).text()`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this : use `.trim()` as there could be a space before / after the text

```
var rowID = $("#@idSelectObjectGuid").val().trim();

$($(".ls-grid-body tr").children(".@vcTable.PrimaryKey")).each(function () {

   alert($(this).text() + " == " + rowID);

   if ($(this).text().trim() == rowID) {

       $(".ls-grid-body tr").removeClass("lst-state-selected");
       $(this).addClass("lst-state-selected");

   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, .trim() it is help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of thing that `filter` is good for:

```
$(".ls-grid-body tr").children(".@vcTable.PrimaryKey").filter(function () {
   return $.trim($(this).text()) == rowID;
}).addClass("lst-state-selected");
```

**Notes:**

- `string.trim()` is not available on all browsers, so use `$.trim()` instead
- You seem to have a redundant $() wrapper.
- You seem to have a mismatch between the elements you `removeClass` and `addClass` to (tr vs tds).